# Date disappear if you use bootstrap date picker

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Pull working example from github, [dateExample](https://github.com/bp12345/dateExample).

I've asked this question before however the suggestion didn't work so I've created a small working example. If someone can point me in the right direction I can put it up online and post the link here. It is a meteor app.

**The problem**

Autoform generates a form with dates. The form works as an array and uses the bootstrap template which provides some `+-` buttons to `add` or `remove` additional entries. When I use `aldeed:autoform-bs-datepicker` a strange problem appears within the form. If you enter a date and hit the `+-` buttons before saving, the dates disappear. If you don't use `autoform-bs-datepicker` this problem goes away.

See the code below, if there is a way I can post the example up online let me know and I'll do it.

Path: `packages.js`

```
twbs:bootstrap
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker
aldeed:autoform-bs-datepicker
```

Path: `Schemas.js`

```
Classes = new Mongo.Collection("Classes");

var Schemas = {};

Schemas.DatesNotWorking = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        optional: true           
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
            "data-date-autoclose": "true",
            datePickerOptions: {
                format: "yyyy",
                startView: "years",
                minViewMode: "years"
            }
        }     
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
            "data-date-autoclose": "true",
            datePickerOptions: {
                format: "yyyy",
                startView: "years",
                minViewMode: "years"
            }
        }               
    }
});


Schemas.DatesWorking = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        optional: true           
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true       
    }
});

Schemas.Subjects = new SimpleSchema ({
    datesNotWorking: {
        type: [Schemas.DatesNotWorking],
        optional: true
    },
    datesWorking: {
        type: [Schemas.DatesWorking],
        optional: true
    }
});


Classes.attachSchema(Schemas.Subjects);
```

Path: `dateExample.html`

```
<head>
  <title>dateExample</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> dateExampleNotWorking}}


  {{> dateExampleWorking}}
</body>



<template name="dateExampleNotWorking">
    {{#autoForm collection="Classes" id="classesForm" type="update"}}

        {{> afQuickField name='datesNotWorking'}}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Update</button>

    {{/autoForm}}   

</template>




<template name="dateExampleWorking">
    {{#autoForm collection="Classes" id="classesForm" type="update"}}

        {{> afQuickField name='datesWorking'}}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Update</button>

    {{/autoForm}}   

</template>
```

Comment: use nitrous.io for free deployment (50 hr only)

Comment: is this really an answer. My question is about a meteor package that the community uses. I would have thought that more developers would be interested in fixing this error. I'm not looking for free development.

Comment: what i meant in the comment that, try to `live it up online` your code so that we can take a look at the error/bug

Comment: ahh ok, now I get it. give me a minute

Comment: ok. I tried to get nitrous.io working but it just kept crashing so I've push it onto github, [link](https://github.com/bp12345/dateExample)

Comment: I think there's a bug on the package itself. you are encouraged to raise an issue in github.

Comment: Noob question how do I do that?

Comment: go here `https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-bs-datepicker/` and you'll see issues button, after that you'll find a new button for creating issues.

Comment: ok that's been done. Hopefully it is sorted soon

Answer (score 0):

In your `packages.js` first add jQuery and than add `rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker`

```
twbs:bootstrap
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
jquery
rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker
aldeed:autoform-bs-datepicker
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Jquery was already installed above as a standard meteor package. I did try removing it and placing the jquery file where you suggested along with removing and reinstalling rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker however it didn't fix the problem.